# Categorical data correlation matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell of categorical and numerical data. I'd like to convert NUTRIENT to categorical data to find a correlation between AIR READINGS and SETTLE PLATE READINGS for both.

I try to convert to a matrix and then try to convert to categorical:

```
A=cell2mat(Air(:,3));
categorical(A)
```

> Error using categorical
>   Creating an instance of the Abstract class
>   'categorical' is not allowed.

Any obvious reason why thid doesn't work?

```
  'AIR READINGS'    []  []  []
    'PHASE' 'SITE'  'NUTRIENT'  '(M)SA'
    1   1   'SG'    'NO'
    1   2   'SG'    'NO'
    1   3   'MG'    'NO'
    1   4   'SG'    'NO'
    2   1   'LG'    'NO'
    2   2   'LG'    'NO'
    2   3   'MG'    'MSSA'
    2   4   'LG'    'MSSA'
    3   1   'SG'    'NO'
    3   2   'LG'    'NO'
```

and

```
'SETTLE PLATE READINGS' []  []  []
'PHASE' 'SITE'  'NUTRIENT'  '(M)SA'
1   1   'SG'    'NO'
1   2   'SG'    'NO'
1   3   'SG'    'NO'
1   4   'SG'    'NO'
2   1   'SG'    'NO'
2   2   'LG'    'NO'
2   3   'MG'    'NO'
2   4   'LG'    'NO'
3   1   'SG'    'NO'
3   2   'NG'    'NO'
3   3   'SG'    'NO'
```

**EDIT:**

I'm importing these data from an excel file but it looks like it's making cells for each individual entry inside the big cell A. .e.g If I type A{2,3} I get SG. This isn't right is it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to convert if you have a cell:

```
NUTRIENT = {'NO' 'NO' 'NO' 'NO' 'NO' 'NO' 'MSSA' 'MSSA' 'NO'}
NUTRIENT_cat =  categorical(NUTRIENT)
NUTRIENT_dummy = dummyvar(NUTRIENT_cat')
```

> NUTRIENT =
>
> ```
> 'NO'    'NO'    'NO'    'NO'    'NO'    'NO'    'MSSA'    'MSSA'    'NO'
> ```
>
> NUTRIENT_cat =
>
> ```
>  NO      NO      NO      NO      NO      NO      MSSA      MSSA      NO
> ```
>
> NUTRIENT_dummy =
>
> ```
>  0     1
>  0     1
>  0     1
>  0     1
>  0     1
>  0     1
>  1     0
>  1     0
>  0     1
> ```

Your categories are:

```
categories(categories(NUTRIENT_cat))
```

> ans =
>
> ```
> 'MSSA'
> 'NO'
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. The nutrient categories are the SG etc column, but in any case, even if i dont try to convert it to a matrix and i type categorical(A(:,3)) i get the error shown above. Is it because i have headers? Is there a way of seeing if its in the corrct format that categorical will accept to start with?

Comment: IF you want to define your own categories (i dont know what you mean by "SG etc column") then read this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html#bt0w1mp-3).  To check if the input is correct: check input equals vector | matrix | multidimensional array. If you still have this issue try to post what you get if you simply write A(:,3).

Comment: Thanks. I mean the NUTRIENT categories are SG, LG, MG etc not the column with MSSA, NO in. It's my fault, I didn't make the data look clear enough.